# Attachments comes only inline

Tags: c#, email, attachment, email-attachments

I attach one file to email, and I set it to come like attachments but it come only inline

```
        Attachment data = new Attachment(filepath);
        data.ContentDisposition.Inline = false;
        data.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Attachment;

        // Add time stamp information for the file.
        ContentDisposition disposition = data.ContentDisposition;
        disposition.CreationDate = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(filepath);
        disposition.ModificationDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(filepath);
        disposition.ReadDate = System.IO.File.GetLastAccessTime(filepath);
        disposition.FileName = filename;
        disposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Attachment;


        // Add the file attachment to this e-mail message.
        message.Attachments.Add(data);
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `new Attachment(file, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);`?

Comment: @Reniuz nothing changes

Comment: How are the attachments "inline" exactly?  Are you adding an <img> tag to the body of the e-mail that points to the attachment?

Comment: That said, System.Net.Mail has undocumented side effects for certain properties.  Try putting "data.ContentDisposition.Inline = false;" just before "message.Attachments.Add(data);"

Comment: @Dave nothing changes, I attach pdf file to email, and this document is represent in line after body text

Comment: That sounds more like an e-mail client being "helpful" than it does like a problem with how you're configuring the e-mail.

Comment: @Dave You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested only in mac Mail, now I tried in gmail and attachments is represent fine, not in line

Comment: Yeah, it looks like Mac Mail displays 1 page PDFs inline automatically.